# Import csv file into postgresql using specific row delimeter

Tags: postgresql, csv

I need to import a csv file into PostgreSQL table. My csv file has specific column delimeter and row delimeter set.

I cannot use the copy command as I cannot specify the specific row delimeter that I am using.

```
\copy table_name FROM '/path/to/csv/import.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

Is there any alternative way I can import the csv file.

Comment: Can you just replace the row delimiter using sed or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to brief how I solved this issue.
The issue I had was my table had new lines in the data. So, I could not use postgreSQL copy command as during import the data could get shifted into another cell.

So, I replaced the new line with specific character(~) and imported the file into postgreSQL.

```
\copy table_name FROM '/path/to/csv/import.csv' DELIMITER '^' QUOTE '$'
```

And then after importing, I replaced the ~ character back to new line.